# Different JSON webtoken per login

Tags: jwt

I am doing an app with a login/logout function and I will be storing the jwt issued by the server in the browser's local storage, for logging out I will destroy it so, if the same user wants to login again it will have to request for a new jwt. However, assuming that i will be using the same credential for the very same user, the same jwt token will be given based on its formula. So, is there a way to issue different jwt per login?

Comment: It depends on how you're generating the JWT but they usually have timestamps in them that will guarantee a different token each time. Also you should NOT be storing credentials in the JWT, just a user identifier.

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked that one. I just realized I can use timestamps in the payload data.